Have the navigation.ros.org site being relocated?
I'm referencing to https://navigation.ros.org for the navigation document.
But, I cannot access the site, since May 9th.
Please, let me know.
Thank you.

If you are looking for Nav2. It has been move to its own site.

Thank you, I accessed to https://docs.nav2.org/
